# Volley no response from HTTP GET

Tags: android, json, android-studio, http, android-volley

I'm trying to retrieve the JSON from an API but I'm not getting anything. 
The JSON :

```
{"coord":{"lon":90.41,"lat":23.71},"weather":[{"id":721,"main":"Haze","description":"haze","icon":"50n"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":25,"feels_like":28.6,"temp_min":25,"temp_max":25,"pressure":1011,"humidity":83},"visibility":3500,"wind":{"speed":1.5,"deg":90},"clouds":{"all":75},"dt":1588093825,"sys":{"type":1,"id":9145,"country":"BD","sunrise":1588029983,"sunset":1588076702},"timezone":21600,"id":1185241,"name":"Dhaka","cod":200}
```

I did add INTERNET permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

My code :

```
    private void httpGet() {
    // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + CITY + "&units=metric&appid=" + API;
    //https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=dhaka,bd&units=metric&appid=5694263c8d821570bfccff2a13246a73
    Log.d("TEST", "Fonction lancee 1/2" + url);

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d("TEST", "Fonction lancee 3/2" + response);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("TEST", "Erreur");
                }
            });
    queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

I also tested with StringRequest with the same result, no response.

EDIT 
My entire classe to see the context :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView tempTxt;
String CITY = "dhaka,bd";
String API = "5694263c8d821570bfccff2a13246a73";
String url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + CITY + "&units=metric&appid=" + API;
//https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=dhaka,bd&units=metric&appid=5694263c8d821570bfccff2a13246a73

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tempTxt = findViewById(R.id.tempTxt);
    httpGet();
    //new weatherTask().execute();
    Log.d("TEST", "TEST OUT CALL");

    Button button2 = findViewById(R.id.definirp);

    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        //Passer a la seconde Activity
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent activity2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity2.class);
            startActivity(activity2);
            finish();
        }
    });

    //Affichage de l'heure
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (!isInterrupted()) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            TextView theure = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);
                            TextView tdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.heure);
                            long date = System.currentTimeMillis();

                            //Format de l'heure
                            SimpleDateFormat sdfTime = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
                            SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy");

                            String timeString = sdfDate.format(date);
                            String dateString = sdfTime.format(date);

                            theure.setText(timeString);
                            tdate.setText(dateString);

                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
}


private void httpGet() {
    // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + CITY + "&units=metric&appid=" + API;
    //https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=dhaka,bd&units=metric&appid=5694263c8d821570bfccff2a13246a73

    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                    tempTxt.setText(response.toString());
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            tempTxt.setText("That didn't work!");
        }
    });
    queue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

You can test the page of my JSON, the address is in comment in my code, (there is a comma in the city), it works.

Comment: can you show the class where you have that function to see what is `this` in that context

Comment: Try this `String url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + CITY + ",&units=metric&appid=" + API;` . Missing `,` after city

Comment: No, my city is like this : String CITY = "dhaka,bd";

Comment: I got this error "Erreur : com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host"

Comment: It's was a DNS problem on my emulator...